# BSD sound problems with Realtek 892

Tags: drivers, freebsd, ati, realtek, pc-bsd

I'm having the same problem as: 
    [No sound with Mint 12 and Realtek ALC892](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26305/no-sound-with-mint-12-and-realtek-alc892?rq=1).
The user marked it as "Resolved" without actually resolving it, he just changed to another OS and gave up.
Has anyone resolved this with BSD or Linux? I'm personally more invested with a BSD solution, but a Linux solution would be VERY similar, and would also help.
My Mobo has the Realtek 892 sound and ATI Radeon HD-4250
(RS780/RSRS880)
Using Kate to edit my config files was a failure.
As soon as I sudo to give kate root privileges to edit said config files,
my root password changes, locking me out.
(3  times in a row with a drive format and fresh install!)
The ISO was downloaded directly from PCBSD.org, so I trust it was not tampered with.

I had seen someone say 5-6 yrs ago that the sound won't work with HDMI out unless the video driver was installed correctly. That would block sound from exiting the HDMI port, because it was on the video driver. But I have no sound from ANY speaker, including rear analog, or HDMI.

BSD properly identifies my sound chip, but I have no sound.
It identifies my video as "ATI", but does not specify.

I don't want to return to Windows, and would rather use BSD than Linux, and I want sound. So, anyone else ever fixed this successfully?